# Remap keys with KeyRemap4MacBook for all apps except a specific one

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-mountain-lion, button-remapping

I'd like to know how do I tell [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to exclude an app from key remapping. I know about `<only>` tag in private.xml, which limits key remapping to a single app, but is there a tag that has the opposite meaning i.e. remapping to all apps but some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<not>MAIL</not>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, KeyCode::A</autogen>
</item>
```

The default application names are defined in [appdef.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/version_8.0.0/src/core/server/Resources/appdef.xml), but you can add new ones in private.xml:

```
<appdef>
<appname>TEXTEDIT</appname>
<equal>com.apple.TextEdit</equal>
</appdef>
```

See http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml-appdef.html.en for more information.

Comment: What about if you want to disable all remaps for a specific application? For example I have a bunch of global settings enabled but I want to disable all of the when I am in the application Sublime Text

Comment: @Noah Just add a `not` element to them like in the example above. If they are predefined settings, you can copy them from [checkbox.xml](https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml) to private.xml.